# Codeigniter num_rows() of $result always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Have the following class to validate the user Login,

```
class Validation_model extends CI_Model {


public function validateLogin($userid,$userpass){    


    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $this->load->database();
    $encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($userpass);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ecom-user');
    $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
    $this->db->where('userpassword', $encrypted_string);

    $result = $this->db->get();


    echo $result->num_rows();




    }


}
```

But when even I entered a valid userid & password it returns the row count as 0, Please help me with this, where I have done the mistake?

Comment: print last query and run in your phpmyadmin

Comment: It also returns Zero :(

Comment: probably $encrypted_string is not working...try inputting password manually in the query and see if it works

Comment: add table name in $this->db->get('table name');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are *encrypting* the password.

The encryption function used by CodeIgniter uses a random initialization vector (IV) every time it encrypts something, which means that the cipher-text (the encrypted text) will be different every time it is encrypted.

When dealing with passwords you need to *hash* them, not *encrypt* them. They are related but they are not the same thing.

- [Wikipedia article on cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)
- [Page on PHP.net on password hashing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)
- [Documentation on PHP's native password hashing API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php)
- [Compatibility library for the native API](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (if you have PHP <5.5.0)
- [PHPass implementation for CodeIgniter on Github](https://github.com/jenssegers/CodeIgniter-Phpass-Library) (if you have PHP <5.5.0)

If you have PHP >=5.5.0 then you can do:

```
$hashed_password = password_hash($userpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// ...
$this->db->where('userpassword', $hashed_password);
```

For this to work you also need to re-hash the passwords in your database.

Comment: Thanks alot, I got it Now!